# How to upload jar and pom to nexus 2 using python requests?

Tags: python, maven, file-upload

I tried to follow the suggestions from [here](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2-) and use python requests instead of curl for uploading a jar file to a maven nexus repository. It works fine for simple jars, but I failed miserably on uploading a jar together with a pom file.

Initially I tried uploading the 2 files together but the pom file was never uploaded. What I ended up with is uploading them one at a time but now, the pom file's content is not uploaded, instead an empty file is uploaded to nexus:

```
    files = {'pom': ('my_lib-10dev-P.pom', open(pom_path, 'rb'))}
    values = {'hasPom': 'true'}
    r = requests.post(self.get_nexus_upload_path_from_lib_coordinates(coordinates, 'pom'), data=values,
                      auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.user, self.password), files=files)

    files = {'jar': ('my_lib-10dev-P.jar', open(resource_path, 'rb'))}
    values = {'hasPom': 'true', 'e': 'jar'}
    r = requests.post(self.get_nexus_upload_path_from_lib_coordinates(coordinates, 'jar'), data=values,
                      auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.user, self.password), files=files)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Both files (x.jar and x.pom are uploaded to the correct path on nexus but the pom file is empty)

The URL path is correct

Comment: What happens if you only upload the pom? Is it complete?

Comment: Same. Empty pom file